# Validate document names in a directory with string inside txt file

Tags: powershell

I am working on a script that validates a filename based on an entry inside a text file, e.g.:

Document_1223.txt, Document_6666.txt, Document_4551.txt, etc...

The text file will contain entries like this (without the whitespace in between):

1223

3221

4551

What I want to do is say, if the document name contains one of the entries in the text file we move it to another directory, if not, we move it to an errored directory.

This is probably something quite trivial but I cannot seem to get it to work how I want it to, I've tried many ways and this is my latest

```
$dwhDocumentsSource = Get-ChildItem "C:\source\documents" -Filter *.edi
$clientCodes = Get-Content "C:\clients\clientcodes.txt"

foreach ($dwhDocument in $dwhDocumentsSource){
    if ($dwhDocument.Basename -contains $clientCodes){
        write-output "Yes its there"
    }
    else{
        write-output "No its not there"
    }
}
```

For now, I am just trying to validate that it actually works, once I can do that I can do the moving part myself.

I am assuming it's not working because it's comparing against the whole content of the txt file and not going over each line. Although I thought Get-Content saves the results in individual strings..

**Edit: I should mention it always returns No its not there.**

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at that `if` condition:

```
$dwhDocument.Basename -contains $clientCodes
```

The `-contains` operator tests if the value passed as the right-hand side operand (in this case `$clientCodes`) appears in the collection passed as the left-hand side operand (in this case `$dwhDocument.Basename`).

If we substitute sample values, it should become apparent why this condition is never satisfied:

```
# This will never be true
if(@('Document_1223') -contains @('1234','3221','4551')){
 # ...
}
```

Instead, you need to flip the logic around, and test if *any* of the client code values can be found in the file's basename, for this I'd personally recommend the `.Where()` extension method:

```
if($clientCodes.Where({$dwhDocument.Basename -like "*_${_}", 'First'})){
  # document name was found to match at least one client code 
}
```

Here, `.Where()` will iterate over the array of possible client codes, test whether the current document base name ends with an underscore followed by the client code. The `'First'` argument will make `.Where()` return as soon as it finds one match, which will speed up processing if you have many client codes to evaluate.

Comment: Hello! This does work but what if the filename is more like this?

Document_(date)_(anotherCode)_(clientCode)_(anotherCode)_(anotherCode)_(anotherCode).edi

With the client code being the one I want to validate? I cant find much info on this part of your answer *_${_}" I understand what it does but don't know how to apply it to my situation.

Thanks!

Comment: @PeterJMac More like what? :)

Comment: Sorry am editing on mobile at the moment its a nightmare..

Comment: `-like` does wildcard string comparison. `*` is a wildcard meaning "anything", the `_` is just a literal `_`, and `${_}` is the same as `$_`. If an underscore always follows the code, do `-like "*_${_}_*"` instead :-)

Comment: Got it, works great thanks for the clear explanation.